# C extend a pointer array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, opencv

I'm trying to extend an array of pointer using realloc here is my minimal code:
I extend the array with this code:

```
YCSImage ** tabImages = NULL;
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
    tabImages = (YCSImage **)realloc(tabImages,i*sizeof(YCSImage *));
    tabImages[i-1] = new YCSImage;
    *(tabImages[i-1]) = Mat(Size(width,height), CV_8UC3, p_pixel_buffer);
}
```

And try to access the data with this code:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   imwrite("../img"+to_string(i)+".png",*(tabImages[i]));
}
```

I got no segfault or anything like that the only problem is that imwrite() writes 5 times the last image I stored in my extended array. (as if for any index I give in my tabImages I get the only same picture tabImages[4])
What's wrong with this code ?

**[Edit]**
I found it by testing this simple code that it is working properly. The problem came from the fact that the p_pixel_buffer is a pointer and change every time in the loop so does the image.

Comment: You have two variables called `tabImages`...

Comment: what is an YCSImage ?

Comment: A Class I made inherited from Mat opencv

Comment: BTW, if you are using C++, you should avoid `realloc`, and use a `std::vector` instead, which will handle all of this for you.

Comment: `tabImages = (YCSImage **)realloc(tabImages` is not a good code pattern unless you check `tabImages` for NULL and terminate your application if it is. If `realloc()` cannot complete the request, it returns `NULL` (and the previous buffer is still valid, but under this code pattern you no longer have a pointer to it).

Comment: I know but I need to use it in a C struct which can't handle reference to a std::vector that's why I'm using pointers here or maybe there is a way to pass a vector to pointer and then get the vector back from the pointer ?

Comment: If this is minimal, then the problem disappears if you change `YCSImage` to, say, `int`. Therefore the problem is in code you haven't shown us.

Comment: mah I check it in my real code but since it is not the problem here I didn't put it here.

Comment: Then can you give us a [minimal *complete* example](http://www.sscce.org/)?

Comment: Ok it seems more details are really needed I will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing all 5 images with the same data `p_pixel_buffer`. Are you modifying it later?

Comment: In fact the p_pixel_buffer changes for every i in my loop. Sorry I tried to sum it up and avoid details but it must be confusing for you.

Comment: Why are you `realloc` it 5 times? Better use an stl container(this would also avoid call to new), or allocate it just once.

Comment: @Chabloz: then the most likely explanation is that the old pointers still point to it, either directly or indirectly.

Comment: You can try priting `p_pixel_buffer` after realloc line.

Comment: @Beta: Yes probably it's what I thought but I have no idea why to be honest

Comment: @Mohit Jain: I already checked the p_pixel_buffer data they are all different and work properly the problem here seems to be that every tabImages with index from 0 to 4 point to the same YCSImage (the last I add with realloc)

Comment: It can give you an idea if p_pixel_buffer is really being changed. If it is changing, next thing you need to track is if data pointed by it is different or not.

Comment: Piece of code you posted looks alright. Error most probably lies in some other part of code.